# Laravel factory relationships... respect create() or make()

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, phpunit

According to Laravel's [documentation on defining relationships within model factories](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database-testing#relationships):

> You may also attach relationships to models using Closure attributes in your factory definitions. For example, if you would like to create a new User instance when creating a Post, you may do the following:

```
$factory->define(App\Post::class, function ($faker) {
    return [
        'title' => $faker->title,
        'content' => $faker->paragraph,
        'user_id' => function () {
            return factory(App\User::class)->create()->id;
        }
    ];
});
```

---

The issue I'm running into is the reference to `create()` within the relationship definition. It seems to me that this doesn't belong here.

It works great if I am wanting to persist my relationships to the database:

```
factory(App\Post::class)->create();
```

By running the code directly above this, a new `App\Post` and a new `App\User` will be created and both persisted to the database.

But if I just want to `new` up the model(s) and not persist anything (at all) to the database by running:

```
factory(App\Post::class)->make();
```

It does what I want up to a certain point. A new `App\Post` instance is created but not persisted, however `App\Comment` is created and is persisted to the database.

---

It seems to me, that what I really want is something like this:

```
$factory->define(App\Post::class, function ($faker) {
    return [
        'title' => $faker->title,
        'content' => $faker->paragraph,
        'user_id' => function () {
            // here I only want to declare the relationship,
            // not decide whether I want to create() or make()
            // the relationship, something like:
            return factory(App\User::class)->createOrMake()->id;

            // or perhaps something like:
            return factory(App\User::class)->id;
        }
    ];
});
```

The end result is that I want the related data to respect what I'm trying to do from the top of the call, down. Make everything. Or create everything.

---

Am I doing something wrong here? Or is this something that doesn't currently exist?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, i'm facing same issue. How did you solve this?

Comment: @Zalo I didn't. :(

Answer (score 2):

You want the lazy() method for your related models!

At least in Laravel 5.5.

I found your question here because I was having the same issue. I found the answer thanks to Laravel's beautifully written code -- lazy() was defined just above the make() XDebug took me to -- and I've tried it out and it seems to work.

This is what I'm doing:

```
$factory->define(App\ArtItem::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        // 'id' => $faker->randomDigit,
        'slug' => $faker->unique->word,
        'artist_id' => factory(App\Artist::class)->lazy(),
        'image_id' => factory(App\Image::class)->lazy(),
        'created_at' => $faker->dateTime,
        'updated_at' => $faker->dateTime,
        'deleted_at' => $faker->dateTime,
    ];
});
```

Lazy() is an interesting creature that returns a closure, so you can't do `factory(App\Image::class)->lazy()->id` but I'm still seeing it successfully setting the correct image_id and artist_id.

I certainly hope you found the solution long before this, but maybe this'll help someone else!

Comment: That looks cool! I need that, but its not working for me... If I define my factory using factory(...)->lazy(), then, when I use make(User::class), it is still calling create() under the hood...

Answer (score 1):

This is finally solvable now using [Factory Callbacks](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/database-testing#factory-callbacks) added in Laravel 5.6.12.

```php
$factory->afterMaking(Post::class, static function (Post $post) {
    if (!$post->user_id) {
        $post->user()->associate(factory(User::class)->make(['id' => 0]));
    }
});
$factory->afterCreating(Post::class, static function (Post $post) {
    if (!$post->user_id) {
        $post->user()->associate(factory(User::class)->create())->save();
    }
});
```

Now, whenever you `make` a Post, if you don't pass it a user_id, it will `make` a User for you and set the relationship without saving it.  But if you `create` a Post, it will persist a new User to the database and save its ID to the Post model.

Note that *both* the `afterMaking` and `afterCreating` closures are called when you `create` a factory model.  I am temporarily setting the User id to 0 in case the foreign key `posts.user_id` was defined `not null`.  It will be updated to the correct value in `afterCreating`.  This is a *terrible* hack, but it works until we get a proper `beforeCreating` hook which would allow us to create the related model first.